# Makefileで変数名とその値を出力するやり方

Tags: makefile

Makefile内で使用される変数の値を出力するのに、
下記のCマクロのような変数名と値を両方表示する書き方はありますか？

```
#define PRINT_VAR(v) printf(#v " is %d", v);
```

echoで下記のようにしてもいいのですが、
上記の方がコピペミスとかあっても気づきやすそうなので

```
@echo "VAR_A is $(VAR_A)"
@echo "VAR_B is $(VAR_A)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make の [Call Function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html#Call-Function) を使って書いてみました。

```
print_var = @echo $(1) is $($(1))

var_a = foo
var_b = bar

.PHONY: test
test:
        $(call print_var,var_a)
        $(call print_var,var_b)
```

```sh
$ make
var_a is foo
var_b is bar
```